# FTP: What happens if the file is modified while being uploaded?

Tags: ftp, file-transfer, file-corruption

I am wondering what would happen in that situation ? I tried to look online but could not find any clear answer.

Let's say I have a huge file (few GB) that I want to transfert to a FTP server.
I open a FTP client and hit send, the file take a few minutes to upload.

But during that upload, some program on my computer comes in and updates the file.
What will be the file on the other end ?

Will it be corrupted ? Or does FTP have some sort of integrity check and realize the file has changed and restart the transfert ?

I am currently asking for FTP but it sounds like a complex problem so I am wondering how other protocols handle it ? (HTTP, SFTP, rsync protocol, ...)

Edit: The reason I am asking is because I am writing a protocol that will need to send data coming from files, and it needs to be resilient to such situations

Comment: Most FTP applications would hold a handle on the file making that impossible. In reality what happens entirely depends on the application being used.

Comment: Run a checksum on the source when you start the copy, and on the target once it's finished. If you want to capture the changes too, you'd need to either start the copy over if it's different, or to identify the chunks that have changed and sync just those.

Answer (score 2):

First, it depends slightly on the OS. In some systems (specifically Windows), a program may hold a file open *exclusively,* preventing any other program from opening the same file for writing (or at all, if needed). This would be the easiest "protection" against updates.

Most other operating systems do not support mandatory locking, however, and always allow multiple programs to write to the same file. Then it depends on 1) whether the update is done "in place" or whether it is done by copying & swapping the files, and 2) whether the FTP software *checks* for modification.

- If another program updates the file in-place (open, seek, write), its changes will be immediately seen by the FTP client once it gets to uploading that part.

  (This is by design; concurrent updates are often used by database file formats, with advisory locking between cooperating programs to negotiate which program gets to update which parts at any time.)
- On the other hand, if the update was done by creating a *new* file and moving it over the old one (as is very often done by text editors), then the FTP client will still have a handle to the *old* file open and will continue to upload it unchanged.

  (If this is done on Windows, the editor will likely fail to "save" the file as it won't be allowed to delete the old version that's still held open. Other operating systems allow this and do a soft deletion instead – the old file will be deleted from the folder but its data still exists for the FTP client to read.)
- Some programs, most commonly backup systems such as tar or Borg, will compare the file's reported modification time before and after the transfer. If the modification time has changed, the program knows that the file must have changed. Backup tools often retry or at least warn the user when that happens.

  But most file transfer clients *do not* do this, and neither do servers. (Except perhaps for rsync?) They assume that if you didn't want a file to be changed, you wouldn't have changed it.

> I am currently asking for FTP but it sounds like a complex problem so I am wondering how other protocols handle it ? (HTTP, SFTP, rsync protocol, ...)

FTP as in the protocol has nothing to offer here, as it is only the *network* protocol and doesn't really cover how software must behave on the computer – such modification checking is entirely the matter of the client software.

(Sure, in theory the protocol could require the client to pre-hash the file like in BitTorrent, but unexpected updates could happen during pre-hashing just as well, in which case the protocol again cannot help with anything.)

For rsync, I believe the client software *deliberately* checks modification times before/after.

Comment: I was asking about the protocol, because if the protocol does not have some FILE_CHANGED_WHILE_READING packet to send to the receiver, the receiver will not be aware that he received a potentially corrupted file and should discard it and restart the transfert. While the Client software is indeed the one doing the check, the protocol needs to support such use-case.

Do you know how rsync client communicates to the receiver that the file has changed ? That would be very insightful

Comment: The receiver doesn't _need_ to be aware. What would be the point of the sender notifying the receiver, just for the receiver to request the sender to restart the transfer, if the sender itself can do so directly? The sender is the one who initiated the transfer in the first place after all.

Comment: It depends, in case of FTP, when using PUT then indeed the sender initiated the transfert and can just restart it again, but in case of GET, it is the other way around. In the case of GET, if the file is modified on the server (sender) while downloading then how can the receiver be aware ?

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's true. (You did however ask about uploads specifically.) But the client can do a similar check – it can query modification time before and after, e.g. via MLSD.

Comment: Yeah sorry, when I asked the question I forgot to mention I was looking for information about both, even If my exemple was only mentioning one. That is a good point, thank you !